Unhandled Exception: SocketException: Connection refused en Flutter

E/flutter ( 3444): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: SocketException: Connection refused (OS Error: Connection refused, errno = 111), address = localhost, port = 52354
E/flutter ( 3444): #0      _NativeSocket.startConnect (dart:io-patch/socket_patch.dart:721:35)
E/flutter ( 3444): #1      _NativeSocket.connect (dart:io-patch/socket_patch.dart:984:12)
E/flutter ( 3444): #2      _RawSocket.connect (dart:io-patch/socket_patch.dart:1902:26)
E/flutter ( 3444): #3      RawSocket.connect (dart:io-patch/socket_patch.dart:21:23)
E/flutter ( 3444): #4      BufferedSocket.defaultSocketFactory (package:mysql1/src/buffered_socket.dart:72:24)

class Mysql {
  static String host = 'localhost',
                user = 'remote',
                password = '1234',
                db = 'prueba';
  static int port = 3306;

  Mysql();

  Future<MySqlConnection> getConnection() async {
    var settings =  ConnectionSettings(
      host: host,
      port: port,
      user: user,
      password: password,
      db: db
    );
    return await MySqlConnection.connect(settings);
  }
}

¿Cómo lo soluciono?

En lugar de usar localhost usa 10.0.2.2

@René ¿de dónde te has sacado esa IP? Puede que efectivamente el problema sea que está apuntando a localhost, pero tampoco le va a solucionar el problema el poner una IP al azar.

@René con eso , me ha salido esto.
E/flutter ( 8806): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: SocketException: Socket has been closed
E/flutter ( 8806):

@Vale estás usando emulador o dispositivo físico? Checa con ipconfig para ver cuál es la dirección IP del dispositivo y usarla en lugar de localhost

@René un emulador de android studio para probar la app.  Restarted application in 1.526ms.
I/flutter (11882): Iniciando consulta...
I/flutter (11882): Conexión establecida con éxito.
I/flutter (11882): Error al ejecutar la consulta: SocketException: Socket has been closed

@René ahi le puse la ip de mi pc y me salio eso.

@Vale la IP de tu PC es localhost, tienes que ponerle la IP del dispositivo del emulador, en algunos casos es 10.0.2.2, por eso tienes que usar ipconfig para checar cual es la IP, actualiza la pregunta con lo que estas haciendo para saber.

@René Porque tendria que poner la ip del emulador si la base de datos esta en m pc  y es donde debe conectarse para poder buscar , insertar datos, etc.?

Lo siento me confundí al explicar, la IP de localhost al emular es 10.0.2.2 como ves en la documentación de acá Set up Android Emulator networking  |  Android Studio  |  Android Developers

Ahora por el otro error, probablemente estes cerrando el socket al querer usarlo, si es desde la web entonces no es compatible, trata de hacer una consulta simple para ver si te trae datos.

por lo que veo estas queriendo conectarte desde un emulador a la base de datos que se encuentra en tu pc, el problema que tienes es que el emulador se toma a nivel de red, como un dispositivo diferente a la pc, más alla de que el emulador corra sobre la pc, este para el router genera una nueva conexión y es un dispositivo totalmente separado de la pc.
Lo que debes hacer es en la pc abrir la consola de comandos(presiona la tecla windows + R y en el cuadro de dialogo ejecuta cmd) y en la consola ejecuta ipconfig.
Debería salirte algo así

en dirección IPv4 te dice tu dirección de red local, esa es la ip que vas a poner en el host. Ten en cuenta que debes otorgar permisos de conexión al puerto en el firewall si lo tenes activado, ya que sinó te va a rechazar todas las conexiones
